# Is it possible to load symbols with just ipsw (without device) for symbolicate?

Tags: ios, crash, symbolicate

I got an app crash report from a client with a iOS 4.3.2 device.
I don't have a device with that version so I downloaded the .ipsw and thought putting it in the xcode Organizer software images section will allow me to symbolicate the iOS logs but it didn't work.
Any idea if this is possible without a device?

Thanks!

Comment: This is not possible, Xcode is doing some processing when fetching the symbols. If you post your full crash report, I could symbolicate them for you. Of course except the app calls, since I would need the dSYM for that.